# M2DOC : How to pass a collection of objects

Tags: m2doc

Is it possible to pass a list of object (PhysicalComponent) to my custom service that prevent me to iterate over all PhysicalComponent ?

Actually I iterarate like this in my M2DOC template :

```
{m:for pc | self.eAllContents(pa::PhysicalComponent)}
{m:pc.MatrixFlow()}
{m:endfor}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a service with the following signatures:

```
public SomeReturnType myService(List<PhysicalComponent> components) {
...
}
```

or

```
public SomeReturnType myService(Set<PhysicalComponent> components) {
...
}
```

or

```
public SomeReturnType myService(Collection<PhysicalComponent> components) {
...
}
```

Then you can call it this way for instance:

```
{m:self.eAllContents(pa::PhysicalComponent)->myService()}
```

The arrow tells to pass the collection to the service, the dot tell to call the service on each element of the collection.

If you used a List of a Set as the first parameter you may need to use asSequence() or asOrderedSet():

```
{m:self.eAllContents(pa::PhysicalComponent)->asSequence()->myService()}
```

or

```
{m:self.eAllContents(pa::PhysicalComponent)->asOrderedSet()->myService()}
```